# Вывод треугольника Паскаля

Tags: c

Нужно написать программку, что будет рисовать треугольник Паскаля. Попробовал написать - показывает только полтреугольника.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for (int i = 0; i <= number-1; i++) {
        for (int spacja = 0; spacja <= number; spacja++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i*2+1; j++) {
            printf("%d",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i*2+1; j++) {
    printf("%d ",j);
}
for (int j = i*2+1; j >= 1; j--) {
    printf("%d ",j);
}
```

У Вас пропущены нечетные строки.

Comment: аутпут должен быть другим)

Comment: @Władysław Меня лично "аутпут" устраивает. Если Вам нужна помощь, потрудитесь написать какой вывод программы Вам нужен, и что Вы получаете. Если Вам что-то непонятно в ответе - задавайте вопросы.